# integrate component

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

are ther any integrate parser mathematical expertion component in delphi?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Pegtop Math Expression Eval](http://pegtop.net/delphi/components/math/intro.htm) component. It is a real bad-ass math component.

Answer (score 0):

Several, have a look [here](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/MathFunctions/Parsers.htm).  efg's site is full of good info for Delphi programmers btw.

Answer (score 0):

(I guess you don't want to do, so it might rather be for other's information...)

If you want to make some numerical caluculating software and you can choose commercial product, take a look at [MtxVec](http://www.dewresearch.com/mtxvec2.html).

It can not only supprt [scripting](http://www.dewresearch.com/MtxScripter.html), but can handle matrix, vectors, complex numbers.

You can [use matrix, vectors with operator overloading(after D2006)](http://www.dewresearch.com/Help/Delphi/MtxVec/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=index.html), so it's easy to use.

It wraps [intel's MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl/) inside, so it's extremely fast. (But I think it might be weak point for deploying MKL's DLL. I wonder if I can choose with/without MKL...)